# hide footer in a specific fluid page with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fluid-layout

First of all, what do I mean by "fluid page"? I mean one long page that is broken into id sections which show those id's as pages. It's most basic structure looks like this:

```
    <div class="mainnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1">PAGE 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">PAGE 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">PAGE 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">PAGE 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5">PAGE 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page1" class="container-fluid"> Page 1 content </div>
    <div id="page2" class="container-fluid"> Page 2 content </div>
    <div id="page3" class="container-fluid"> Page 3 content </div>
    <div id="page4" class="container-fluid"> Page 4 content </div>
    <div id="page5" class="container-fluid"> Page 5 content </div>

    <!-- sticky footer -->
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

So as you can see whenever the you hit the menu item for that ID, the content slides up until it reaches that Id and it displays the content as if it was a different page. Easy enough!

My problem is, I have the footer sticky and I did that so that when you click to the next page (ID) the footer is still there, EXCEPT, I don't want it to show when #page1 is selected.

I attempted to build a small JS, but my JS is less than great. Here is my attempt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideFooter(){
        $("#homeContainer").css(display:none);
    }

         $(document).ready(function() {
             hideFooter();
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, not working.  Here is a [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/taHCv/1/) that you can use.

Any ideas!?

Comment: That's the most feeble attempt I think I have ever seen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/taHCv/4/

Comment: @GitaarLAB The content and styles is irrelevant. Even if the page was empty it has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @GitaarLAB - That's a problem with JS Fiddle. If you open the console, you'll see an error. My *seven lines* of code does nothing with the actual site.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you, your code gave me a general idea on how to work this out. The fiddle was solved perfectly, but that was also a much simpler version of what I am building so I'll still need to get it worked. But as I said, my JS is not great so, feeble it was indeed.

Comment: You should post it an answer. So that I can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a handler on the `.mainnav a` tags and toggle as appropriate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Viewport();
    $(window).bind('resize', Viewport);

    $('.mainnav a').click(function(){
        if (this.href.indexOf('#page1') == -1) {
            $('.footer').show();
        } else {
            $('.footer').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/taHCv/4/